# Trouble installing rspec

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install rspec 2.9.9, as I am working through a course that isn't compatible with 3. My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173433/rake-aborted-could-not-find-rspec). I run the command:

```
sudo gem install -v '<3.0.0' rspec
```

and this comes up:

```
Successfully installed rspec-2.99.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rspec-2.99.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for rspec-2.99.0...
```

Then when I use "dpkg" to check what version is installed, this is returned:

```
dpkg-query: package 'rspec' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` (as well as `apt-get` and `aptitude`) work with Ubuntu's package system while `gem` uses the ruby gem system.

Both can be considered "package managers", but they are not the same, they're distinct. Things installed via `gem` can't be found in the `dpkg` database and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I run "rake" like it says in the tutorial, it returns
    
   `rake aborted!
    Gem::LoadError: Could not find 'rspec' (~> 2) among 65 total gem(s)
    Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-    2.2.1:/home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global', execute `gem env`     for more information
    /home/david/TheOdinProject/RubyProject/learn_ruby/Rakefile:2:in     `<top (required)>' `

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
In gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.9.9'
end
```

Then run `bundle install` in console after that you need to initialize the spec/ directory with:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

I hope it will help you. Let me now if it's work or not.